# How can I transform an existing Maven Java project to a Scala project for the Scala IDE?

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

A library has available an example project that I cloned from github. It is a Java project and uses Maven for dependency management. I would like to just add some Scala code to the project. I'm using the Eclipse Scala IDE.

Comment: Just add src/main/scala as a tree folder and write your scala code there.

Comment: @AvihooMamka You mean just create the folder and that's it?

Comment: Yes, under `src/main` create the folder `scala` and place your scala code there. You might encounter in packaging both Scala and Java files. If that happens, show the error and I'll try to assist

Comment: So I added the folder. I ran "mvn package" and "mvn eclipse:eclipse", but the folder isn't showing up as a package in Eclipse and it also seems that Eclipse isn't recognizing the Scala files I added to the folder as Scala files somehow.

Comment: Do you use the Scala plugin for your IDE?

Comment: Yes. It's the Scala IDE

Answer (score 0):

Maven does not support Scala by default, you need to enable scala-maven-plugin. Here's the configuration in `<plugins>` section of pom.xml that I use:

```
    <plugins>

        <!-- other plugins ... -->

        <!-- set scala plugin before compiler plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
                <javacArgs>
                    <javacArg>-Xlint:unchecked</javacArg>
                    <javacArg>-Xlint:deprecation</javacArg>
                    <javacArg>-encoding</javacArg>
                    <javacArg>${compiler.encoding}</javacArg>
                </javacArgs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

After that, place your Scala code in `src/main/scala` folder, and tests in `src/test/scala`, and you should be fine.

Current plugin version is 3.2.1, I think. Here's a link to [official documentation](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_java.html).